# Compare 2 csv files and delete rows - Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a 2 csv files. One has several columns, the other is just one column with domains. Simplified data of these files would be

file1.csv:

```
John,example.org,MyCompany,Australia
Lenny,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

file2.csv:

```
example.org
google.es
mysite.uk
```

The output should be

```
Lenny,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

I have tried this solution
`grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv >output-file`

Found here
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/177207-removing-duplicate-records-comparing-2-csv-files.html

But since there is no explanation whatsoever about how the script works, and I suck at shell,  I cannot tweak it to make it work for me

A solution for this would be highly appreciated, a solution with some explanation would be awesome! :)

EDIT:

I have tried the line that was suppose to work, but for some reason it does not. Here the output from my terminal. What's wrong with this?

```
Desktop $ cat file1.csv ; echo
John,example.org,MyCompany,Australia
Lenny ,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,mysite.com,ThirCompany,US
Desktop $ cat file2.csv ; echo
example.org
google.es
mysite.uk
Desktop $ grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv
John,example.org,MyCompany,Australia
Lenny ,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,mysite.com,ThirCompany,US
```

Why `grep` doesn't remove the line

```
John,example.org,MyCompany,Australia
```

Comment: why would ``mysite.uk`` match ``site.com`` in the last row?  does the ``TLD`` not form part of the string match?

Comment: this `grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv` works fine with your input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you posted, works just fine.

```
$ grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv
Lenny,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

And here's an explanation. [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) will search for a given pattern in a given file and print all lines that match. The simplest example of usage is:

```
$ grep John file1.csv
John,example.org,MyCompany,Australia
```

Here we used a simple pattern that matches each character, but you can also use regular expressions (basic, extended, and even perl-compatible ones).

To invert the logic, and print only the lines **that do not match**, we use the `-v` switch, like this:

```
$ grep -v John file1.csv
Lenny,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

To specify more than one pattern, you can use the option `-e pattern` multiple times, like this:

```
$ grep -v -e John -e Lenny file1.csv 
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

However, if there is a larger number of patterns to check for, we might use the `-f file` option that will **read all patterns from a `file`** specified.

So, when we combine all of those; reading patterns from a file with `-f` and inverting the matching logic with `-v`, we get the line you need.

Answer (score 0):

One in awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($2 in a==0)' file2 file1
Lenny,domain.com,OtherCompany,US
Martha,site.com,ThirdCompany,US
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '    # using awk, comma-separated records
NR==FNR {      # process the first file, file2
    a[$1]      # hash the domain to a
    next       # proceed to next record
}
($2 in a==0)   # process file1, if domain in $2 not in a, print the record
' file2 file1  # file order is important
```